# Name of Solitaire that is similar to Carpet

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire

Looking for name of solitaire game my mom taught me in the 70's.

- I think it was 2 decks.
- Deal cards in a grid form, maybe 5x5 not sure of size:

  1. First card face up, rest down,
  2. repeat with 2nd card up, rest down,
  3. 3rd card face up, rest down, etc until all cards are dealt into these piles in grid,
- unsure of a stockpile.
- Object is to put cards aces up and kings down 8 spaces at top. You
  put the face up cards in grid up top in order then flip over next
  card. You win when all cards are put up top and removed from grid.
- [Carpet game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpet_(solitaire)) is similar except only 1 card in each pile on grid. I am
  sure the each of piles have more than one card except for first card.

Comment: Hi. I believe it would help if you could provide a picture. It's hard to imagine the grid accurately from your description.